# Is it possible to use if statement outside a function (like main)?

Tags: c++, if-statement, static, queue

I'm implementing a BOOOS - Basic oriented-Object Operational System, and now I need to make my program's scheduler choose between FCFS and Priority. I have a class called Task, where I create two queues: `std::queue` and a `std::priority_queue`. Those queues are static members declared in Task.h, and I need to initialize then before any other thing in the Task.cc with the others static members of the class, like this:

```
namespace BOOOS {

    volatile Task * Task::__running;
    Task * Task::__main;
    int Task::__tid_count;
    int Task::__task_count;
    std::queue<Task*> Task::__ready;
    std::priority_queue<Task*> Task::__ready;

    (rest of the Task.cc)

}
```

You can see that I have two __ready queues. That's why I need to use only one of then. If the user want to initialize a FCFS Scheduler, I use the one with no priority, and if the user want a priority Scheduler, I use the priority_queue. This is controlled by a BOOOS's static enum member. So, here's my question: Can I use something similar to `if` in this part of the code to choose only one queue instead of creating two and make an `if` everytime I need to manipulate it in my program?

Comment: What is the deciding factor for them to pick either the FCFS or Priority? Are these things that could be one time only, or dependant?

Comment: The ideal is to make only one type of scheduler, indeed, but in this case I need to make work for both of them. College stuff!

Comment: Have you thought of wrapping them in an object, and then letting that object decide based on whichever predication you have for that choice?

Comment: Just a comment: `volatile` should not be used for threads but only for signal handlers.

Comment: An aside: `std::priority_queue<Task*>` does not order the elements in the way you probably think it does, it will order based on the values of the memory addresses of the elements not using the `operator<` of `Task`.

Answer (score 6):

No that's not possible through using an `if()` statement. These need to be placed inside a function body actually.

Your options are

- use the C-preprocessor and have a

  ```
  #if !defined(USE_PRIORITY_QUEUE)
  std::queue<Task*> Task::__ready;
  #else
  std::priority_queue<Task*> Task::__ready;    
  #endif
  ```

  preprocessor directive.
- use a template class and a specialization

  ```
  template<bool use_priority_queue>
  struct TaskQueueWrapper {
       typedef std::queue<Task*> QueueType;
  };

  template<>
  struct TaskQueueWrapper<true> {
       typedef std::priority_queue<Task*> QueueType;
  };

  TaskQueueWrapper<true>::QueueType Task::__ready;
  ```